# AntiForgeryToken form value does not changes per request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I have a strange issue occurring between different server environment with the same code base where AntiForgeryToken does not changes per request, does anyone know why this could be occurring?

Comment: Any code which is wrong? Any attempt to make it work?